# Data truncated after importing a MySQL 5.7 dump into MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump, mysql-8.0, truncate

I am trying to import a 12G MySQL 5.7 dump (on ubuntu 16.04) into a MySQL 8.0 database (on ubuntu 20.04).

Half way through the import exits and returns the following error:

```
ERROR 1265 (01000) at line 4439: Data truncated for column 'NORM' at row 14
```

Now this seems a likely problem as the original data was having trouble to import from a CSV file for that particular table, however I believed this has been solved after all it is stored now inside the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  NORM from table

N1

N3
N2
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `NORM` enum('N1','N2','N3') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

How can I verify and fix this on the original database and how can I sort of ignore this error while importing from this particular dump for now?

Comment: Check it out by doing  a `SELECT some_fields, (LENGTH(NORM)) AS len FROM your_table_my_sql_5.7 ORDER BY len DESC` - post the result here - some_fields is to provide some context... Also, please upload the outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE blah\G` from both MySQL instances...

Comment: Thanks, that brought us closer. This is an ENUM field without defined empty values but there are empty values. A select distinct reveals an empty value despite 3 other valid values. Now how to fix that?

Comment: Put this further info **into the question**! Also, please provide the info that I requested.

Comment: Isolate the offending line(s) - how is it/are they different from the others?

Comment: I added the info to the question

Comment: Use the -f option - i.e. `mysql -u userName -p -f -D dbName < script.sql` - if this works, I can write it up as an answer? I'd still like to know **how** it's failing - i.e. deal with the problem rather than the symptoms. MySQL has a row length limit of 65,535 bytes - are you exceeding that? However, if it's able to be stored in MySQL 5.7.x, I'm **very** surprised that it  won't work for MySQL 8...

Comment: The -f option made the import run through, however the affected table is entirely empty. Looks like there is no way around then fixing the origin (set NULL where norm = '') and then dumping again.

Comment: Take a look at the dump file. Isolate the table with the norm field. Check out the data being input - see if you can use sed & awk to change it so that it's acceptable... Post some data on pastebin and we can have a look?